# How can I get Zend Db to return a rowset rather an array when performing a UNION query?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a result set that is the result of a MySQL UNION query. The code I am using to fetch the data is:

```
$union_select = $PagesTable->getAdapter()->select()
        ->union(array('(' . $legal_resources_select . ')', '(' . $pages_select . ')'));
$PagesTable->getAdapter()->fetchAll($union_select)
```

`$PagesTable` extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`. The full select is too big to post here and I don't think it is relevant to this particular question. If I am wrong let me know.

Currently this is returning an array of results, but I want it to return a rowset object. I must also be able to specify the `$_rowClass`. This is necessary so I can add methods for formatting and manipulating the returned values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The result set you are fetching is a composite, and not a set of Rows from the DB, so even if it were possible, its a pretty bad idea.

Zend_Db_Table is an implementation of the Table Data Gateway pattern more than Active Record.

What you describe would be possible usually under Active Record, and to do so, I'd suggest looking at Doctrine 1.2 rather than Zend_Db_Table.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you want to specify the rowClass or rowsetClass, you can do that with the Zend_Db_Table class by calling the following methods

Using Zend_Db_Table's methods `setRowsetClass` and `setRowClass`:

```
class RowTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    private static $_instance;
    protected $_name = "tableName";
    protected $_primary = "primary_key_id";

    # over-write the default class Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract
    # make sure the following classes are inside the include-path
    private function __construct($rowClass, $rowsetClass) {
        $this->setRowsetClass("ContributionList");
        $this->setRowClass("Contribution");
    }
}

$tableObject = new RowTable("RowClass", "RowsetClass");
```

Comment: Or as class properties eg. `$_rowClass`

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I know this is really old, but the ones who get to this page should know that, a `Zend_Db_Adapter` always returns arrays, so when you use the `Zend_Db_Table::getAdapter` method, you are actually getting away from your table class and using the fetch method contained on the adapter class which returns array, rather than the `Zend_Db_Table::_fetch` which returns objects under the Data Gateway pattern.

So the first answer is wrong, the result set will be a row-set with many row objects but without what doctrine calls data hydration, so expect many redundant data on the row objects.

I see this mistake done by a lot of people where I work, I wonder why so many people uses the `getAdapter` method. Another thing to mention is that, when you use the `getAdapter` to get the select object, you are not getting the right select object, you are getting a `Zend_Db_Select` and you will need a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` so u can use on the `Zend_Db_Table::_fetch` method which is used by the `fetchAll` and `fetchRow` methods.

Cheers.